# Static class variable in Python that isn't copied for each instance

Tags: python, oop, static-variables

I need a way to create a static class variable in Python that only the class will have. I can't afford this variable to be created over and over again for each instance, because the target class variable will be a huge read-only data structure. Each instance must be able to access it for read-only purposes throught the class, but since it's a giant bulk of data and there will be thousands instances, I can't afford that each instance will create another copy of this data structure again.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python), but it doesn't solve my problem, because the static class variable suggested is created for each instance:

```
>>> class MyClass():
    i = 1
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.i
1
```

In other words, I'm looking for a static class variable like in PHP:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public static $my_static = 'foo';
}

$foo = new Foo();
print $foo::$my_static . "\n";     // Accessable throught the class
print $foo->my_static . "\n";      // Undefined "Property" my_static     
?>
```

This is exactly what I need, the static class variable is created only once for the class, all instances can access it throught the class but this static class variable isn't created over and over for each new instance. Is it possible to create a static class variable like this in Python?

PS: I now there are some workarounds if I don't use OOP, but if I could find a good and clearly readable OOP solution it would make more sense in the project as a whole.

Comment: Why do you think that just because you can _access_ it as `m.i` it's actually getting _created_ multiple times?

Comment: *"the static class variable suggested is created for each instance"* - no, that's not correct.

Comment: That you can acces it from an instance does not mean it is created for each instance.

Comment: @tzaman isn't it? If I assign a new value for `m.i` it will be different from `MyClass.i`

Comment: @renatov why would you assign a new value to the instance?

Comment: @renatov **if** you assign `m.i` on an instance, at that point it creates a new one, shadowing the class var.

Comment: @tzaman hmmm I didn't know Python worked like this. So `m.i` and `MyClass.i` are the same if I just access them as read-only?

Comment: @renatov yup, exactly.

Comment: @tzaman thank you very much for your help! I'm still learning Python and the OOP part is very unclear to me yet. I read the documentation, but a lot of things were left apart, unfortunately. Thanks again!

Comment: @tzaman where exactly did you learn all these things about Python OOP? The material I've read so far have never mentioned something like that. Did you study Python OOP by a particular book or tutorial?

Comment: @renatov no specific books; the main Python tutorial and the page about the data model are instructive though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the static class variable suggested is created for each instance

That is false, as you can easily demonstrate:

```
>>> class Test():
    class_attr = []


>>> t1 = Test()
>>> t2 = Test()
>>> t1.class_attr is t2.class_attr
True  # this means that they reference exactly the same object
>>> t1.class_attr.append(1)  # alter via t1
>>> t2.class_attr
[1]  # see the changes via t2
```

However, you can *override* the class attribute with an instance attribute:

```
>>> t1.class_attr = []
>>> t1.class_attr is t2.class_attr
False
```

so if you need to *replace* the class attribute (rather than alter it in-place, as the `append` did) you should do so via the class, not the instance (in this case, `Test.class_attr = []` would have affected both `t1` *and* `t2`).

Comment: where did you learn Python OOP? All the documentation I've read has never mentioned anything like what you pointed out. Did you read some particular book or tutorial?

Comment: @renatov I can't answer specifically, but note that this is covered in e.g. the official Python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass():
    i = 1

inst = MyClass()
```

All attributes of a class are stored in `__dict__`. It contains `i` (in addition to a bunch of other things):

```
>>> MyClass.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>,
'__module__': '__main__', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'MyClass'
 objects>, 'i': 1, '__doc__': None})
```

The instance does not have any attributes:

```
>>> inst.__dict__
{}
```

If `i` cannot be found in `inst.__dict__` the search continues in `MyClass.__dict__`. Even though it looks a bit like the instance has an attribute `i`, it actually exist in the class only.

As soon as you assign to the instance:

```
inst.i = 10
```

the this changes:

```
>>> inst.__dict__
{'i': 10}
```

Now, the instance has its own attribute.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! The OOP part in Python is very confusing to me. I'll start using the `__dict__` to  check what is created and what is not.

Comment: @renatov note that you can have `__slots__` instead of `__dict__`, and the built-in types don't have either, so this isn't always possible